# Where can I check what version of the Linux Kernel is released for 12.04?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, kernel, 12.04

Well I am using a newer kernel on my Ubuntu 11.10 as the stable 3.0.0-14 version was causing laggy sound on my PC. After upgrading my kernel to the latest version for the 12.04 Alpha (3.2.0-8) the sound issue was solved. I upgraded by temporarily changing my sources to 12.04 ones, upgrading kernel, then switching back. I would like to know how to check which is the latest version of kernel for 12.04 so I can know when I should upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://packages.ubuntu.com enables you to get an overview of all supported operating systems. For instance, searching for Linux; http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=linux, will show that 3.2.0-8 is the current version in Precise.

For a commandline tool, you can use `rmadison` from the [devscripts](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/devscripts) package. It will present results like this (skipping most):

```
jo-erlend@dev:~/$ rmadison linux
     linux | 3.0.0.12.14 |       oneiric | amd64, i386
     linux | 3.0.0.14.16 | oneiric-security | amd64, i386
     linux | 3.0.0.14.16 | oneiric-updates | amd64, i386
     linux | 3.0.0.15.17 | oneiric-proposed | amd64, i386
     linux | 3.2.0-8.14 |       precise | source
     linux |  3.2.0.8.8 |       precise | amd64, i386
```

Comment: From those links, you can download the kernel .deb directly, and install it with dpkg , might be easier then updating your sources.

Comment: Well will I get all the dependencies while installing with DPKG?

Comment: yes, but you would need to download the headers separate. Other then the kernel headers , what dependencies ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to monitor kernel updates yourself by occasionally checking the ubuntuupdates.org website.

For the precise linux-generic package the website URL is http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/linux-generic